# AngularJS > Cycle through JSON files using Next, Previous buttons

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a portfolio site, where MAIN shows a list of projects from projects.json, then each project has its own page workTemplate.html, pulling in data from a titleX.json file.

Main project list (click) --> Title.json (each page) [previous /next button] --> another Tile.json

How would I cycle through each work page using previous/next buttons from each workId page?

I have setup a Plunker to show my setup:  http://plnkr.co/edit/zU9bz73Iv4ya0MIAE3f5?p=preview

I think i need to use a factory:

```
      query: {method:'GET', params:{workId:'works'}, isArray:true}
```

But not sure.

My Plunker is not 100% working, but you get the idea. Most appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the list of entire projects.
As soon you get the list in main.html's `controller`, you can have an array(or a service, later) where you maintain the list of all the `work.id`

Say you have your list in `var myList = ['test1','test2','test3'];`. You can get the current `work.id` from `$stateParams.workId`. Get the index of current work.id from `myList` into `currentWorkIndex`.

Say you are currently at `test2`, so previous is `test1` and next is `test2` Get their indexes as.

```
prevWorkInd = (currentWorkIndex !== 0) ? currentWorkIndex - 1 : 0;
nextWorkInd = (currentWorkIndex !== l - 1) ? currentWorkIndex + 1 : l - 1; //l is length of myList
```

Now you have index of both previous and next monitor.Hence the `work` is found. Store it something like :
`$scope.prevWorkId = myList[prevWorkInd];
$scope.nextWorkId = myList[nextWorkInd];`

In your HTML, you can use prev and next using

`<a ui-sref="work({workId:prevWorkId})">Previous</a>
<a ui-sref="work({workId:nextWorkId})">Next</a>`.

Now, instead of storing `myList` inside of controller, you can use a service which will return the entire list. I am sure this is not the only place where you will be using this.

**EDIT :** Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lAK69fOfLg05P9p9dkoJ?p=preview) for the soln.
Note that this code can still be optimized.

Comment: thanks for this Aniket. This explanation is good for someone with experience with Angular JS, however for me I think I need examples on Plunker. I will keep trying to make what you have described and let you know the result. However I think that it's too difficult for me to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Keep trying on plunker, let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: OK, Plunker is down right now, will keep you posted :)

Comment: sorry for the delay in getting back to this problem. I tried your method, but it didn't work for me. The closest I got was using 

`$scope.nextWork = function() {
        var workId = $stateParams.workId;
        var path = ('/work/' + $stateParams.workId + 1);
        $location.path(path);
      };`
http://plnkr.co/edit/zU9bz73Iv4ya0MIAE3f5?p=preview

But this didn't work either. Can you explain a little more or provide a demo URL, so I can try with your method again?

Comment: Edited the soln with plunk link. I saw your code, but I don't think you should redirect throught your javascript using `$location.path(path);`. If you must, you should use `$state.go()`.
I am sure the given plunk will guide you to optimize the code even more.

Comment: Aniket - this is awesome! Great solution, thanks. OK, i will replace `$location` with `$state.go()`. One last thing, is there anyway to make the loop start from 1 again after reaching the last work (or 3 if going to previous from 1) in the Array? I will have a think about that :)

Comment: I designed the code in such a way that if you click previous from 1st item or next from last item, it'll stay there, since there is nowhere to go. You can always change the logic to use modulus(`%`) to go back to the 1st item.

Comment: thanks so much Aniket. In the end to loop through i used the following 
`var prevWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== 0) ? (currentWorkIndex - 1) : (l - 1);
        var nextWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== l - 1) ? (currentWorkIndex + 1) : (0);
        $scope.prevWork = $scope.allWorks[prevWorkIndex].id;
        $scope.nextWork = $scope.allWorks[nextWorkIndex].id;` 
Thanks again and merry xmas :)

Comment: Well, that's a better approach. Merry Christmas.